# PHP - How can I tell in which domain a script will look for cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to fix a really elusive bug where I lose my session upon redirect.

In my local setup, there is no problem; it only manifests itself on the live site. I discovered that my local version was creating two identical cookies: one for `.mydomain.com` and one for `www.mydomain.com`. However, the live site creates only one cookie for `.mydomain.com`.

It seems as though my script is looking for the `www.mydomain.com` cookie, which is why there's no apparent problem on the local server.

How do I determine to which domain a given script will look for its cookies? (or if this sounds like a different problem, please let me know)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php  make that's identical between servers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setcookie(key, value, expire_time, '/')` this will add cookie for your site's document root, either www.domain.com or domain.com will work fine.